# Correct usage of dplyr::select in dplyr 0.7.0+, selecting columns using character vector

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang, tidyeval

Suppose we have a character vector `cols_to_select` containing some columns we want to select from a dataframe `df`, e.g.

```
df <- tibble::data_frame(a=1:3, b=1:3, c=1:3, d=1:3, e=1:3)
cols_to_select <- c("b", "d")
```

Suppose also we want to use `dplyr::select` because it's part of an operation that uses `%>%` so using `select` makes the code easy to read.

There seem to be a number of ways which this can be achieved, but some are more robust than others.  Please could you let me know which is the 'correct' version and why?  Or perhaps there is another, better way?

```
dplyr::select(df, cols_to_select) #Fails if 'cols_to_select' happens to be the name of a column in df 
dplyr::select(df, !!cols_to_select) # i.e. using UQ()
dplyr::select(df, !!!cols_to_select) # i.e. using UQS()

cols_to_select_syms <- rlang::syms(c("b", "d"))  #See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656993/how-to-pass-a-named-vector-to-dplyrselect-using-quosures/44657171#44657171)
dplyr::select(df, !!!cols_to_select_syms)
```

p.s. I realise this can be achieved in base R using simply `df[,cols_to_select]`

Comment: As an alternative use the .vars argument: `select_at(df, .vars = cols_to_select)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an example with `dplyr::select` in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlang/vignettes/tidy-evaluation.html that uses:

```
dplyr::select(df, !!cols_to_select)
```

Why? Let's explore the options you mention:

### Option 1

```
dplyr::select(df, cols_to_select)
```

As you say this fails if `cols_to_select` happens to be the name of a column in df, so this is wrong.

### Option 4

```
cols_to_select_syms <- rlang::syms(c("b", "d"))  
dplyr::select(df, !!!cols_to_select_syms)
```

This looks more convoluted than the other solutions.

### Options 2 and 3

```
dplyr::select(df, !!cols_to_select)
dplyr::select(df, !!!cols_to_select)
```

These two solutions provide the same results in this case. You can see the output of `!!cols_to_select` and `!!!cols_to_select` by doing:

```
dput(rlang::`!!`(cols_to_select)) # c("b", "d")
dput(rlang::`!!!`(cols_to_select)) # pairlist("b", "d")
```

The `!!` or `UQ()` operator evaluates its argument immediately in its context, and that is what you want.

The `!!!` or `UQS()` operator are used to pass multiple arguments at once to a function.

For character column names like in your example it does not matter if you give them as a single vector of length 2 (using `!!`) or as a list with two vectors of length one (using `!!!`). For more complex use cases you will need to use multiple arguments as a list: (using `!!!`)

```
a <- quos(contains("c"), dplyr::starts_with("b"))
dplyr::select(df, !!a) # does not work
dplyr::select(df, !!!a) # does work
```

Comment: Thank you, that answer is excellent - great to have clarification of why the `!!!` and `!!` solutions both work, and the dput/rlang example is great to help me solves problems like this in future